# I am not able to parse the mag and place and time as in nested class of JSON in app they all show value as null

Tags: android, json, kotlin, okhttp

code is present inside this link https://github.com/Pranjul120568/AndroidPracticeQuakeReport. and link to the api https://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/ci39540463.geojson

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Response instead of Property at parsing

Problem at line number 31 :

```
val quake=gson.fromJson(response, Properties::class.java)
```

Solution:

```
val quake = gson.fromJson(response, Response::class.java)
```